# Initialize future data in a Flutter StateNotifier + Riverpod architecture

Tags: firebase, flutter, clean-architecture, riverpod

So I was implementing the architecture showed by ResoCoder on YouTube at this article: https://resocoder.com/2020/12/11/flutter-statenotifier-riverpod-tutorial-immutable-state-management/#t-1607415476843.

I have some problems understanding what's the best approach to initialize future data following his scheme.

Let's say I have the dummy Repository class:

```
abstract class WeatherRepository {
  Future<Weather> fetchWeather(String cityName);
}

class FakeWeatherRepository implements WeatherRepository {
  double cachedTempCelsius;

  @override
  Future<Weather> fetchWeather(String cityName) {
    // Simulate network delay
    return Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 1),
      () {
        final random = Random();

        // Simulate some network exception
        if (random.nextBool()) {
          throw NetworkException();
        }

        // Since we're inside a fake repository, we need to cache the temperature
        // in order to have the same one returned in for the detailed weather
        cachedTempCelsius = 20 + random.nextInt(15) + random.nextDouble();

        // Return "fetched" weather
        return Weather(
          cityName: cityName,
          // Temperature between 20 and 35.99
          temperatureCelsius: cachedTempCelsius,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class NetworkException implements Exception {}
```

WeatherState class:

```
abstract class WeatherState {
  const WeatherState();
}

class WeatherInitial extends WeatherState {
  const WeatherInitial();
}

class WeatherLoading extends WeatherState {
  const WeatherLoading();
}

class WeatherLoaded extends WeatherState {
  final Weather weather;
  const WeatherLoaded(this.weather);
}

class WeatherError extends WeatherState {
  final String message;
  const WeatherError(this.message);
}
```

The WeatherNotifier:

```
class WeatherNotifier extends StateNotifier<WeatherState> {
  final WeatherRepository _weatherRepository;

  WeatherNotifier(this._weatherRepository) : super(WeatherInitial());

  Future<void> getWeather(String cityName) async {
    try {
      state = WeatherLoading();
      final weather = await _weatherRepository.fetchWeather(cityName);
      state = WeatherLoaded(weather);
    } on NetworkException {
      state = WeatherError("Couldn't fetch weather. Is the device online?");
    }
  }
}
```

Both providers:

```
final weatherRepositoryProvider = Provider<WeatherRepository>(
  (ref) => FakeWeatherRepository(),
);

final weatherNotifierProvider = StateNotifierProvider(
  (ref) => WeatherNotifier(ref.watch(weatherRepositoryProvider)),
);
```

And the WeatherSearchPage (UI):

```
...
child: Consumer(
  builder: (context, watch, child) {
    final state = watch(weatherNotifierProvider.state);
    if (state is WeatherInitial) {
      return buildInitialInput();
    } else if (state is WeatherLoading) {
      return buildLoading();
    } else if (state is WeatherLoaded) {
      return buildColumnWithData(state.weather);
    } else {
      // (state is WeatherError)
      return buildInitialInput();
    }
  },
),
...
```

where

```
Widget buildInitialInput() {
    return Center(
      child: CityInputField(), // builds a textfield to fetch the weather of some city
    );
}
```

and

```
  Widget buildLoading() {
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
Column buildColumnWithData(Weather weather) {
    return Column(
       ...
       //shows data
       ...
    );
  }
```

If I would need to fetch a default city weather when the page is created, where should I call it following this logic?

I tried converting the WeatherSearchPage (UI) into a stateful widget and calling in the initState like so

```
@override
  void initState() {
    context.read(weatherNotifierProvider).getWeather("Siena");
    super.initState();
  }
```

which works but doesn't seem very clean and doesn't take advantage of the InitialState of the widget.
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Here are two examples of using StateNotifier and the new AsyncNotifier StateNotifier https://gist.github.com/biniama/9b959e92a336da2340dd6918fca97d62 https://gist.github.com/biniama/4ba5140f525f8717bef367872484611b

Answer (score 2):

First of all, using a StateNotifier here doesn't make much sense. It's not wrong, but I think I can show you an easier way to do this that really takes advantage of what Riverpod has to offer.

You could use a [FutureProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/all/FutureProvider-class.html) and wrap the contents of the component with the [AsyncValue](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/all/AsyncValue-class.html) states.

```dart
class FakeWeatherRepository implements WeatherRepository {
  double cachedTempCelsius;

  static final provider = Provider<FakeWeatherRepository>((_) => FakeWeatherRepository());

  @override
  Future<Weather> fetchWeather(String cityName) async {
    // Get weather
  }
}

final weatherProvider = FutureProvider.family<Weather, String>((ref, city) {
  final repo = ref.watch(FakeWeatherRepository.provider);
  return repo.fetchWeather(city);
});

class WeatherWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const WeatherWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: watch(weatherProvider('Siena')).when(
        data: (weather) => Center(
          child: Text(weather),
        ),
        loading: () => Center(
          child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
        error: (err, stack) => Center(
          child: Text(err.toString()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then you could of course use some state provider or ValueNotifier, etc. to change the string you are passing to the `weatherProvider`.

I hope this helps, I know I didn't exactly answer your question but I couldn't let you continue your Riverpod journey without the power of AsyncValue!